# R shiny leaflet bubble map by Count

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to make a Shiny app that uses some Geographical data I have stored in MySQL. The data currently contains a list of Longitudes and Latitudes (of client location), client age, client gender, and other various demographics. For example:

```
+--------+-------+--------+---------+
| Member | Long  |  Lat   | Gender  |
+--------+-------+--------+---------+
| A      |    34 |   -118 | M       |
| B      |    34 |   -118 | F       |
| C      |    41 |    -74 | M       |
| D      |    39 |    -77 | M       |
+--------+-------+--------+---------+
```

I want to use `leaflet` to create a bubble map for the locations - a bigger bubble at a location means that more clients are present at that area. It seems like the function `addCircles` does this pretty well, but the problem is that I don't have a count of the number of clients at each location to assign to the `radius` parameter- each row in my table represents information for a particular client, not a location. Is there a way to obtain that info?

My best guess is to create a new table where each row represents counts for a different longitude and latitude and then use a count column to count the number of times that location appears among clients, but I'm not sure if this is the best way since it involves creating a new table, and I would have to create additional columns like "number of males" and "number of females" for every factor I want to account for. And what if I wanted to adjust my map for females who are in the age range of 40-50? The number of columns I would have to create would easily exceed 100..

Comment: You don't need to precompute each column, you can dynamically compute the count using inputs you set in shiny, then aggregate by lat long and plot it.

Comment: Make sure is that lat long are approximated as in your example so grouping by these numbers will aggregate several members.

Comment: How would I go about doing that though? I read that once the selectbox(es) have been used I can adjust my `df` to filter out entries like `df1 <- df[df$gender == input$gender, ]` but I still don't know how to aggregate by lat and long

Comment: Have a look at `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarise`. Also checkout how to use `shiny::reactive` to filter your dataset according to input